# Change text of NSButton in NSTableCellView after click

Tags: swift, view, nstableview

I have a table of custom `NSTableCellView`s that contain embedded `NSProgressIndicator`s and `NSButton`s that I would like to update both immediately after a click, and periodically, on a timer. This is a sample of my code thus far:

```
func sound(sound: NSSound, didFinishPlaying aBool: Bool) {
    pbNowPlaying.doubleValue = sound.currentTime
    if aBool == true {
        self.btnPlay.stringValue = "Play"
        self.btnPlay.state = NSOffState
        self.pbNowPlaying.doubleValue = 0
    }
    self.needsDisplay = true
}
```

This (and other code where `self.needsDisplay = true` is set) does not seem to update the view. When I manually reload the table data, the progress bar moves (having been bound to the `NSSound`s `.currentTime` value), but the button text/state does not change.

Any advice?

Coding using Swift, Xcode 6.4, OS X 10.10.4

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Well, I feel rather dumb, but for anyone else who might be running into the same problem: To modify the text on an `NSButton`, you need to change the `.title` property, not the `.stringValue` property.